# Count distinct values in one column provided the 2nd column value is not the same in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a database in which there are multiple columns. I am trying to find **distinct** web pages visited provided the time stamp on these pages are not the same. For example:

```
Sno User   Page    Timestamp
1    A    google   18.00
2    A    yahoo    18.00
3    A    bing     19.00
4    A    facebook 20.00
5    A    insta    21.00
6    A    twitter  21.00
7    A    bing     22.00
```

the result should be:

```
User  Count
A     4
```

Google and yahoo has same-time stamp so it should count as 1 page visited and not 2, similarly insta and twitter has same time stamp so should also count as 1. Also, since bing is coming again in the end, it should not count that as the user has already visited that earlier. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whish RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using ssms

Answer (score 0):

you can  use rank  function

```
select User_, count(distinct timestamp) as count
from (
    select *, rank() over (partition by User_, page order by timestamp) grp
    from t
) t1
where grp = 1
group by User_
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/31979/6

```
User_   count
A         4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using `row_number` to get the first instance to each page visited by user, and then you can use `count` with `distinct` to get the total you need, but I'm not understanding why you want to return `sno = 1`:

```
select user, count(distinct timestamp)
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by user, page order by timestamp) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
group by user
```

If you need `sno = 1`, you could use `min(sno)`, but again, not sure why.

Comment: Oh sorry, so 'SNO' doesnt matter. I just need to count distinct pages provided the time stamp is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple CTE. Assuming the data is:

```
create table t1 (
  sno int,
  usr varchar(10),
  page varchar(10),
  ts int
);

insert into t1 (sno, usr, page, ts) values (1, 'A', 'google', 18);
insert into t1 (sno, usr, page, ts) values (2, 'A', 'yahoo', 18);
insert into t1 (sno, usr, page, ts) values (3, 'A', 'bing', 19);
insert into t1 (sno, usr, page, ts) values (4, 'A', 'facebook', 20);
insert into t1 (sno, usr, page, ts) values (5, 'A', 'insta', 21);
insert into t1 (sno, usr, page, ts) values (6, 'A', 'twitter', 21);
insert into t1 (sno, usr, page, ts) values (7, 'A', 'bing', 22);
```

The query could be:

```
with g (p, c) as (
  select max(page), count(*)
    from t1
    group by ts
)
select count(distinct p) as my_count from g;
```

Result:

```
my_count     
--------
4
```

Or... you can also do:

```
select count(distinct p) from (
  select max(page) as p, count(*) as c
    from t1
    group by ts
) x;
```

with the same result.